# Lemma for any integrable function

Tags: integration

I found this Lemma in a book called "Mutational and Morphological Analysis_ Tools for Shape Evolution and Morphogenesis" (J.P. Aubin)

it is necessary for understanding the rest. I have difficulties to understand the proof specially the first equation.

> Lemma : Let us consider an integrable function $e(.)$. Then
>   \begin{equation} \int_0^{t} dt_1 \int_0^{t_1} e(s) \frac{(t_1 - s)^{n-1}}{(n-1)!} ds = \int_0^{t} e(s) \frac{(t - s)^{n}}{n!} ds 
> \end{equation}
>
> Proof: we observe that
>   \begin{equation}
> \int_0^{t} dt_1 \int_0^{t_1} e(s) \frac{(t_1 - s)^{n-1}}{(n-1)!} ds =\int_0^{t} e(s)ds \times \int_s^{t} e(s) \frac{(t_1 - s)^{n-1}}{(n-1)!} dt_1 =\int_0^t e(s) ds \left[\frac{(t_1 -s)^n}{n!}\right]_s^t =  \int_0^{t} e(s) \frac{(t - s)^{n}}{n!} ds 
> \end{equation}

1) What techniques he used to passe in the first equality ?

2) how can he enters the terme $[\frac{(t_1 -s)^n}{n!}]_s^t$ inside the integral while it depends on s ?

Any suggestion is helpful.

Comment: Can you see what the region of integration in the first integral is?  What about the second?  As to the second question, he's integrating with respect to $s$, so there's no problem having a function of $s$ in the integrand.  What is it about this that troubles you?

Comment: the region is [0,T]. for the second as i know the function should be constant so we can enter the function inside the integral or the inverse !

Comment: Sorry, the region of integration is a triangle.  Why should the function be constant?  Look at rubikscube09's answer.

Comment: yes i got the point, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For fixed $t$, the region of integration is a triangle in two dimensions with height and length $t$. This region is given by:
$$
\{(t_1,s) \in \mathbb{R}^2 : 0\leq t_1 \leq t, 0 \leq s \leq t_1\}
$$
By Fubini, we may first fix $t_1$ and then $s$, and integrate the other way. The region may be rewritten as:
$$
\{(t_1,s) \in \mathbb{R}^2 : s\leq t_1 \leq t, 0 \leq s \leq t\}
$$
giving us the new integral

$$\int_0^{t}  \left[\int_0^{t_1} e(s) \frac{(t_1 - s)^{n-1}}{(n-1)!} ds \right]dt_1 = \int_0^{t}  \left[\int_{s}^{t} e(s) \frac{(t_1 - s)^{n-1}}{(n-1)!} dt_1 \right]ds$$

In the second part, the $s$ does not matter, because you fix $s$ in the outer integral, evaluate the inner integral ($s$ stays fixed) and then integrate with respect to $s$ at the end.

Comment: i guess that the new form of the region by Fubini is what was missing me, thank you , big thumbs up, for the second part you mean it just notation !

Comment: Yes, exactly that. Glad I helped!